# Modern CMake transitive Dependency not found

Tags: cmake, build-system

I am currently working on implementing a ROS library into our company software stack. Because the library is based on ROS and thus uses catkin I am rewriting the library to use cmake exclusively and try to apply the [modern CMake approach](https://www.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/effective-cmake). The library is structured as follows:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- LICENSE
|-- README.md
|-- grid_map_core
|   |-- CHANGELOG.rst
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- cmake
|   |   `-- grid_map_core-extras.cmake
|   |-- grid_map_coreConfig.cmake
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- grid_map_core
|   |       `-- iterators
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- iterators
|   `-- test
```

If I install the library and try to add the library in a simple test_project to the target I get an error displaying the Eigen3 dependency cannot be found:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/grid_map_core/grid_map_coreConfig.cmake

  but it set grid_map_core_FOUND to FALSE so package "grid_map_core" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  grid_map_core could not be found because dependency Eigen3 could not be
  found.
```

Unfortunately the Eigen version I have to use does not provide the `Eigen3Config.cmake` option and I am forced to use the cmake provided `FindEigen3.cmake` alternative.
(I suppose compiling a newer Eigen3 version manually would be a valid alternative, nevertheless I try to completely understand the modern cmake approach which looks very promising for exactly avoiding such issues)

From all the resources online I am not quite sure how the transitive dependency is handled in this case.
To my understanding the `grid_map_coreConfig.cmake` should forward the imported Eigen3 dependency.
In the `grid_map_core` CMakeLists the eigen is found by the command `find_package(Eigen3 3.2 REQUIRED)` and the `find_dependency` macro just wraps this exact same command.

### Resources

The main CmakeLists.txt looks as follows:

```
# Set cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

# Set project name
project(grid_map)

# Must use GNUInstallDirs to install libraries into correct
# locations on all platforms.
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)


# Add subdirectories
add_subdirectory(grid_map_core)
```

The grid_map_core CMakeLists as follows:

```
# Set cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

# Set project name
project(grid_map_core)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

# import Eigen3
find_package(Eigen3 3.2.2 REQUIRED)

## Define Eigen addons.
include(cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}-extras.cmake)

#########
# Build #
#########

# Add the library target
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/BufferRegion.cpp
  src/GridMap.cpp
  src/GridMapMath.cpp
  src/Polygon.cpp
  src/SubmapGeometry.cpp
  src/iterators/CircleIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/EllipseIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/GridMapIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/LineIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/PolygonIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/SlidingWindowIterator.cpp
  src/iterators/SubmapIterator.cpp
)

# set target include directories
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
  PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)

# add an alias
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::${PROJECT_NAME} ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

# set target compile options
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Werror>
)

###########
# Install #
###########

# 'make install' to the right locations
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

# This makes the project importable from the install directory
# Put config file in per-project dir.
install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
  FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake"
  NAMESPACE "${PROJECT_NAME}::"
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

# generate config.cmake
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file("${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION "${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION"
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
  )

# install config.cmake files
install(FILES "${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")

###########
# Testing #
###########
```

and the grid_map_coreConfig.cmake as follows:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

find_dependency(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/grid_map_coreTargets.cmake")
```

and the `test_project`'s CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test_project)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(grid_map_core REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_executable(test_project main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_project
  PRIVATE
    grid_map_core::grid_map_core
  )
```

For completeness I'm adding the `FindEigen3.cmake` file:

```
# - Try to find Eigen3 lib
#
# This module supports requiring a minimum version, e.g. you can do
#   find_package(Eigen3 3.1.2)
# to require version 3.1.2 or newer of Eigen3.
#
# Once done this will define
#
#  EIGEN3_FOUND - system has eigen lib with correct version
#  EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR - the eigen include directory
#  EIGEN3_VERSION - eigen version

# Copyright (c) 2006, 2007 Montel Laurent, <montel@kde.org>
# Copyright (c) 2008, 2009 Gael Guennebaud, <g.gael@free.fr>
# Copyright (c) 2009 Benoit Jacob <jacob.benoit.1@gmail.com>
# Redistribution and use is allowed according to the terms of the 2-clause BSD license.

if(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION)
  if(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR)
    set(Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
  endif(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR)
  if(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MINOR)
    set(Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MINOR 91)
  endif(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MINOR)
  if(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_PATCH)
    set(Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_PATCH 0)
  endif(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_PATCH)

  set(Eigen3_FIND_VERSION "${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_MINOR}.${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION_PATCH}")
endif(NOT Eigen3_FIND_VERSION)

macro(_eigen3_check_version)
  file(READ "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h" _eigen3_version_header)

  string(REGEX MATCH "define[ \t]+EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _eigen3_world_version_match "${_eigen3_version_header}")
  set(EIGEN3_WORLD_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
  string(REGEX MATCH "define[ \t]+EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _eigen3_major_version_match "${_eigen3_version_header}")
  set(EIGEN3_MAJOR_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
  string(REGEX MATCH "define[ \t]+EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _eigen3_minor_version_match "${_eigen3_version_header}")
  set(EIGEN3_MINOR_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

  set(EIGEN3_VERSION ${EIGEN3_WORLD_VERSION}.${EIGEN3_MAJOR_VERSION}.${EIGEN3_MINOR_VERSION})
  if(${EIGEN3_VERSION} VERSION_LESS ${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION})
    set(EIGEN3_VERSION_OK FALSE)
  else(${EIGEN3_VERSION} VERSION_LESS ${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION})
    set(EIGEN3_VERSION_OK TRUE)
  endif(${EIGEN3_VERSION} VERSION_LESS ${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION})

  if(NOT EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)

    message(STATUS "Eigen3 version ${EIGEN3_VERSION} found in ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}, "
                   "but at least version ${Eigen3_FIND_VERSION} is required")
  endif(NOT EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)
endmacro(_eigen3_check_version)

if (EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

  # in cache already
  _eigen3_check_version()
  set(EIGEN3_FOUND ${EIGEN3_VERSION_OK})

else (EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

  find_path(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
      PATHS
      ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
      ${KDE4_INCLUDE_DIR}
      PATH_SUFFIXES eigen3 eigen
    )

  if(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
    _eigen3_check_version()
  endif(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

  include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
  find_package_handle_standard_args(Eigen3 DEFAULT_MSG EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)

  mark_as_advanced(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

endif(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Comment: It looks like `find_dependency()` call cannot find your `FindEigen3.cmake` script. Where this script is located?

Comment: Hm, I cannot find [a notion](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) that `FindEigen3.cmake` is a part of CMake, but let it be. `find_dependency` macro calls `find_package()` inside, and the latter one should print a useful message if it fails. But I don't see that message in your output. If your test project uses QUITE keyword when search `grid_map`, then remove that keyword.

Comment: BTW, I remember old `FindXxx.cmake` scripts which sets result via variable `XXX_FOUND` instead of `Xxx_FOUND`. While `find_package` command may check both spelling of the variable, `find_dependency` [checks](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake) only the `Xxx_FOUND` one. I am curious, whether your `FindEigen3.cmake` script sets `EIGEN3_FOUND` variable. (More suspicious: If `find_package()` is called with *REQUIRED* keyword and fails, then it should **immediately** terminate CMake. But your output is **after** `find_package` call.)

Comment: I might be mistaken that the `FindEigen3.cmake` is part of cmake but I believe it was part of Eigen version 3.2.2. before they started to doing it the 'right way' and ship a `Eigen3Config.cmake`. I'm not at the office PC so I cannot really investigate too much myself. 
Nevertheless since the library builds, the file is at least found in one project and the question remains why it cannot be found in the test project. 
I will provide the `test_project` `CMakeLists.txt` asap but it really is just straight forward finding the `grid_map` library and linking it.

Comment: As I said, possible reason would be: `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` finds `EIGEN3_FOUND` variable to be TRUE and interprets Eigen3 as found, so your library build has been succeed. The same (or similar) call is performed when your library is searched, and again, `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` interprets Eigen3 as found. But, after it returns, `find_dependency(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` checks `Eigen3_FOUND` variable (note on the case!). Because this variable is not set, `find_dependency` interprets Eigen3 as not found.

Comment: so I will try to use `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` instead of `find_dependency()` once I'm back at the working station again. It;s really frustrating to find so little patterns and resources for cmake in contrast to c++.

Comment: when using find_dependency() neither variable is set because the command seems to fail and thus is aborted. When using find_package() a linker error occurs which can be dealt with by removing `target_link_libraries(PUBLIC Eigen3)` since eigen is header only. So using `find_package()` in the `grid_mapConfig.cmake` works. When using `find_dependency()` the same original error occurs.

Comment: Show `FindEigen3.cmake` which you use. At least, add a link to it. As Eigen3 is header-only, why do you ever `find_dependency` for it? Are your public headers (which are available for user of your library) includes Eigen3 ones?

Comment: I am just reckoning that Daniel Pfeifer mentions to ALWAYS include dependencies like this: 
`find_package(Foo 1.0)`
`target_link_library(target PUBLIC/PRIVATE Foo::Foo)`
even if the library is header only. But since the `FindEigen3.cmake` does not support this paradigm I only have to add the eigen headers to my public headers and can forget about the dependency. So Maybe the newest Eigen version supports this modern cmake paradigm which I really like and wanted to adapt in this case (where it obviously does not work this way).

Comment: *Header-only* libraries are not usual, and many guides doesn't describe them. With `find_dependency` you require the library to **exist on user machine**. This is absolutely needed for "normal" (shared) libraries, because without them your library wouldn't work at all. But if your library uses some header-only only **internally** (in its implementation, but not in the public interface), there is no point to require that header-only library to be installed on the user machine. All headers from it are already compiled into your library.

Comment: In my case the Eigen library is used in the `GridMap` interface thus it is an 'Interface dependency' and must exist on the user machine, so setting a dependency on eigen would be natural (even though it is header only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you got is generated by `find_dependency` macro, but not by `find_package` command, which is called internally by that macro. Because you call `find_dependency` with *REQUIRED* keyword (and this keyword is passed to inner `find_package`), the only possible scenario of your error is follow:

1. Call to `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` interprets Eigen3 to be **found**.
2. But when `find_dependency` checks `find_package` results, it interprets Eigen3 to be **not found**.

Rather strange, isn't it?

Actually, your `FindEigen3.cmake` script is one of the old ones, which sets **upper case** flow of "FOUND" variable, which denotes success of the script:

> #  EIGEN3_FOUND - system has eigen lib with correct version

but the **correct** name of such variable should be `Eigen3_FOUND` (the package name should be exactly the same as in `find_package(Eigen3)` call and in the name of the script `FindEigen3.cmake`).

Command `find_package` checks both spelling of the "FOUND" variable: correct one and upper-case one. Such way, when `FindEigen3.cmake` script sets `EIGEN3_FOUND` variable with intention "I have found the package", `find_package` understands that intention, marking the package as **found**.

But macro `find_dependency` checks only correct name of the variable, `Eigen3_FOUND`. Because this variable isn't set by the `FindEigen3.cmake` script, the package is treated as **not found**.

As a fast fix, you may replace in the `FindEigen3.cmake` script `EIGEN3_FOUND` with `Eigen3_FOUND`, and everything should work. (Well, the same replacement should be done on the user machine. Or you should ship corrected `FindEigen3.cmake` script with your library).

Comment: Good answer, Further than that I had to remove the `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Eigen3)` since the linker will not find a header only library. This semantics should be correct in newer versions where a `Eigen3Config.cmake` is provided but I will have to verify. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: "This semantics should be correct in newer versions where a `Eigen3Config.cmake` is provided" - Eigen3 installs its target with `install (TARGETS eigen EXPORT Eigen3Targets)` and exports it with `install (EXPORT Eigen3Targets NAMESPACE Eigen3:: ...)`, so the **proper target name** for link with Eigen3 would be `Eigen3::eigen`. Note, that when use namespaced target name, CMake **requires** existence of the target. This is opposite to the non-namespaced target `Eigen3`: if the target isn't exist, CMake *silently* passes it to the linker.

Comment: Yep I forgot the namespace in this case. Already excited to try this once our system is upgraded to ubuntu.