# Modern Cmake can't find Eigen library depency

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen3

long story short: I have a library **myLib** which depends on **Eigen3** that I am trying to use in a simple **test project**. Everything work well in **myLib** and I can use **Eigen3** without issues but I can't say the same for the **test project** that fails to build and raises the following

```
 fatal error: Eigen/Geometry: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <Eigen/Geometry>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now, more in details:

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160869/modern-cmake-transitive-dependency-not-found) but not quite the same.
I am writing a library that depends on Eigen3 and I am doing this using modern cmake and following [this guide](https://unclejimbo.github.io/2018/06/08/Modern-CMake-for-Library-Developers/).
My library works and finds Eigen3, I can *make* and *install* it and use the target for tests. The problem is when I try to use it in external projects as a simple one that I am using to test if it works fine (spoiler alert: it doesn't).

This is myLib library structure:

```
myLib
    - examples
        - tests
            - some tests
    - cmake 
        - myLib-config.cmake.in 
    - include
        - some includes
        - myalgo.h
    - src
        - some src
        - myalgo.cpp
        - CMakelits.txt #2
    - CMakelits.txt #1
```

with CMakeLists.txt #1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# project name and version
project(myLib
  LANGUAGES CXX
  VERSION 0.0.1
)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# add subdirectories
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(examples)
```

and CMakeLists.txt #2:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED) 

add_library(myLib
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/myAlgo.cpp
)
add_library(myLib::myLib ALIAS myLib)


option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared library" ON)
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(myLib
  EXPORT_MACRO_NAME MYLIB_API
  EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/myLib/core/common.h
)

# Compiler Options
get_target_property(Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIRS Eigen3::Eigen INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options(myLib PRIVATE
  $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>>:
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-O0 -Wall -Wextra>>
  $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/Od /Wall /Zi>>
  )

target_include_directories(myLib
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )

target_link_libraries(myLib
  PUBLIC
    Eigen3::Eigen
    yaml-cpp
)

set_target_properties(myLib PROPERTIES
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(INSTALL_CONFIGDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/myLib)

# install compiled library and install include directory and dependencies
install(TARGETS myLib
  EXPORT myLib-targets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myLib
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/myLib
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(EXPORT myLib-targets
  FILE myLib-targets.cmake
  NAMESPACE myLib::
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/myLib-config-version.cmake 
  VERSION ${myLib_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

configure_package_config_file(
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/myLib-config.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/myLib-config.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR} 
)  

install(
  FILES
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/myLib-config.cmake
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/myLib-config-version.cmake
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR} 
)

export(EXPORT myLib-targets
  FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/myLib-targets.cmake
  NAMESPACE myLib::
  )

export(PACKAGE myLib)
```

and last the myLib-config.cmake.in:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

if(NOT TARGET myLib::myLib)
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib-targets.cmake)
endif()
```

Then I make and install the library and use it in my test project by `find_package(myLib)` which works fine until I try to import `<myLib/myalgo>` which uses Eigen3 and causes the following error when trying to build:

> In file included from ~/Desktop/modern-cmake/examples/simple-project/simple_example.cpp:4:
> /usr/local/include/myLib/myalgo.h:16:10: fatal error: Eigen/Geometry:
> No such file or directory
> 16 | #include <Eigen/Geometry>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.

The main question is: how can I have eigen to be carried along myLib?

I do also have a secondary question: I have the feeling that I am not importing yaml-cpp correctly, any hint on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Just for being sure: In your test project, aside from `find_package(mylib)`, you do `target_link_libraries(test_exe myLib::myLib)`, don't you? Also, you may look into the  **exact command line**, used for compiling your test, and check whether Eigen include directory is among of its parameters. (Obtaining exact command line depends on the build tool. E.g. with Make you could use `make VERBOSE=1`).

Comment: Just a guess... Can you move `find_package` commands to the top-level CMakeLists.txt file before `add_subdirectory` commands?

Comment: @Tsyvarev oh, I was so focused on finding issues in the library that didn't take the bother to double check that. That solved the problem. If you want to re write as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @adembudak previous comment solved my issue, I was being blind. Thank you for your time.